# C.A.R. Hoare Quicksort implementation in Java

Tags: java, quicksort

I am trying to implement QuickSort on an array of ints.

All my methods function correctly except for the partition. The partition starts with getting the midpoint, then ordering, first, middle, last.

Comes out to {1,6,5,4,3,2,7}

then somewhere after this I get {1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6} as the final outcome

Can anyone tell me where I can make adjustments?

expected output should be {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args) {


    int [] a = {7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

    quickSort(a);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

}

    public static void quickSort( int [] a) {
        quickSort(a,0,a.length - 1);
    }

    public static void quickSort(int [] a,int start,int end) { 
        if(start<end) {
            int pivotIndex = partition(a, start, end);
            quickSort(a,start,pivotIndex-1); // sort left partition
            quickSort(a,pivotIndex+1,end); // sort right partition
        }

    }

    public static  int partition(int [] a, int start, int end) {
        int mid =midpoint(start,end);
        sortFirstMiddleLast(a,start,mid,end);


        swap(a,start,end-1);
        int pivotIndex = end -1;
        int pivotValue = pivotIndex;

        int indexFromLeft = start +1;
        int indexFromRight = end -2;
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            while (a[indexFromLeft]<a[pivotValue]) {
                indexFromLeft++;
            }
            while (a[indexFromRight]>a[pivotValue]) {
                indexFromRight--;
            }
            if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {
                swap(a,indexFromLeft,indexFromRight);
                indexFromLeft++;
                indexFromRight--;
            }
            else {
                done=true;
            }

        }
        swap(a,pivotIndex,indexFromLeft);
        pivotIndex=indexFromLeft;
        return pivotIndex;
    }

    public static void sortFirstMiddleLast(int [] a, int start, int mid, int end) {
        if (a[start]>a[mid]) {
            swap(a,start,mid);
        }
        else if (a[mid]>a[end]) {
            swap(a,mid,end);
        }
        else if (a[start]>a[end]) {
            swap(a,start,end);
        }
        else if(a[start] > a[mid]) {
            swap (a,start,mid);
        }

    }
    private static void swap(int[] a, int first, int second) {
        int temp = a[first];
        a[first] = a[second];
        a[second] = temp;
    }



    private static int midpoint(int first, int last) {
        return first + (last - first) / 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether if start =< array.size -1 and end >= 0 before execute futher after lines :

```
int indexFromLeft = start +1;
int indexFromRight = end -2;
```

terminate recursions on that condition.

Comment: getting [1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the class created below, you won't have any problems.

```
class QuickSort{
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high]; 
    int i = (low-1); 
    for (int j=low; j<high; j++)
    {

        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;


            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }


    int temp = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;

    return i+1;
}

void sort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {

        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        sort(arr, low, pi-1);
        sort(arr, pi+1, high);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
       swap(a,start,end-1);
            int pivotIndex = end -1; // removed -1
            int pivotValue = pivotIndex;

            int indexFromLeft = start +1; // removed +1
            int indexFromRight = end -2;  // removed -2
```

```
  public static  int partition(int [] a, int start, int end) {
            int mid =midpoint(start,end);
            sortFirstMiddleLast(a,start,mid,end);


            swap(a,start,end-1);
            int pivotIndex = end ;
            int pivotValue = pivotIndex;

            int indexFromLeft = start ;
            int indexFromRight = end;
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) {
                while (a[indexFromLeft]<a[pivotValue]) {
                    indexFromLeft++;
                }
                while (a[indexFromRight]>a[pivotValue]) {
                    indexFromRight--;
                }
                if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {
                    swap(a,indexFromLeft,indexFromRight);
                    indexFromLeft++;
                    indexFromRight--;
                }
                else {
                    done=true;
                }

            }
            swap(a,pivotIndex,indexFromLeft);
            pivotIndex=indexFromLeft;
            return pivotIndex;
        }
```

Comment: It works! thank you. Any idea how I would go about solving this same problem with an Object of arrays?

Comment: Try it why? What's different? How does this solve the problem?